# How can I apply node template file only to node view page but not revision page?

Tags: 6, theming, nodes

I have a node template named `node-"content-type-name".tpl.php` which overrides the default node.tpl.php for this content type.

But this template file is applied to also node revision pages. Is there anyway I can apply the node template file to just node view/edit page without revision page?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a D6 site around with revisions enabled so I can't test this, but the following code should disable the custom template for the revision pages:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$vars) {
  $template_name = 'node-content-type-name';

  // Work out if we're on a revision page
  $on_revision_page = arg(0) == 'node' && is_numeric(arg(1)) && arg(2) == 'revisions';

  // See if the rogue template file is available as one of the suggestions.
  $template_index = array_search($template_name, $vars['template_files']);

  if ($on_revision_page && $template_index !== FALSE) {
    // Remove the rogue template file from the suggestions.
    unset($vars['template_files'][$template_index]);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but it doesn't work and throw this error  `warning: array_search() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given in` for this line `$template_index = array_search($template_name, $vars['template_files']);
`